# How to iterate over mysql rows returned by group by clause?

Tags: php, mysql

I have rows in database something like this:

### title   |   type

sample1 | A
Sample2 | A
sample3 | C
Sample4 | B
sample4 | C
sample6 | A
and so on...

so i fetch all the results from db using php,now the issue i'm getting is it prints the rows in order by id and title but i want to iterate over 5 results of each type until all rows get printed.

For eg: 
Here is my code:
sample1 | A
Sample6 | A
sample8 | A
Sample7 | A
sample9 | A
sample4 | B
sample12 | B
sample16 | B
sample18 | A
and so on...

```
$query = "select group_concat(title),type as sample_name from table_name group by type";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$query))
{
 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
 {
  echo $row['sample_name] . ' belongs to type '. $row['type'];
 }
}
```

Comment: Your logic to iterate over the result set looks correct, but your `echo` statement looks off to me.

Comment: i updated query variable

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
select group_concat(title) as sample_name from table_name
```

you are selecting only `title` with an alias `sample_name` and in php:

```
$row['type']
```

you are using `type` index which is not in result set.